# Syncing with S3: Errno 24 too many open files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a bit of a head scratcher for me because I've done this same procedure with the same types of documents multiple times. No issues before and the last refresh was as recent as October.

I have project that involves downloading and parsing a large batch of PDFs quarterly. There are about 1.1 million at each release. Each PDF is 3-4 pages so the files are pretty small. I do everything with them locally but then push from the external SSD to S3 once downloaded to have a backup.

I'm currently attempting to refresh. It gets about 50 files in and then I get the error

`fatal error: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

None of the files are open.

Pretty straightforward but this is what I'm doing in terminal

```
> screen
> aws s3 sync '/Volumes/G-DRIVE slim SSD USB-C/DOF PDFs/NPV_all' s3://dof.taxdocs/NPV
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Edit:

I tried setting ulimit to 65536/200000 which did not work. I also tried reverting to an earlier AWS CLI 2.X which also did not work. Finally I hooked the external SSD up to my laptop and it's syncing fine from there. On that machine ulimit is set to 256 which tells me that is not the issue. However it is running aws-cli/1.11.28 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.4.85. OS is Mojave 10.14.6 (same as the desktop which is encountering the problem). I *strongly* suspect this is a bug in the more recent versions of AWS CLI. If anyone else runs into this in the future I would first try the most recent AWS CLI (hopefully no bugs by then) and then revert to a version 1.X.

Comment: `EMFILE 24 Too many open files`  is coming from the system,  as "Files" include network sockets, which are a type of file on Unix-based systems. So you can try increasing the [Number of Open Files Limit](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The max Sierra is letting me set it to is 65536/200000. I get the error after roughly the same number of files. I'm also not sure how a setting in the OS could be causing the problem given that this worked fine on the same machine just a few months ago. Is it possible the files being on an external drive could be an issue? That's the only difference I can think of.

Comment: actually, there is a workaround to increase more and you can go till `2147483647`  which the limit of `SIGNED INt`  you can check in this post  [Why does setting the hard-limit for maxfiles to “unlimited” using `launchctl limit` result in a hard-limit slightly above the soft-limit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366319/314762)

Comment: It's a long shot, but I'd make sure you're using the latest version of the AWS CLI, there were some bugs that were fixed long ago around keeping sockets around for longer than needed.

Comment: aws-cli/2.1.26 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/18.7.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off. Is it possible I should try an older version?

Comment: Nope, that should be fine.  Ah well, it was worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, I think you should try an older version of awscli if this used to work fine. It could be a recently-introduced bug, for example.

Comment: @jarmod, see edits for full explanation but I believe an older version did the trick. Haven't tried on the same machine with the issue yet but that seems to be the only difference between the working machine and the one hitting errno 24.

Comment: I had same issue with
`aws-cli/2.5.8 Python/3.9.12 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off`

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure your awscli is up to date to latest version, eg `brew upgrade awscli`
2. Check `aws configure get s3.max_concurrent_requests` for current limit - maybe you forgot that you've set up in the past (like myself .-.) to something like `200`
3. Set to a sensible value again: `aws configure set s3.max_concurrent_requests 10`

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if that will count as an answer, but I had similar issue, and fix for me was to upgrade awscli, from:

```
aws-cli/2.5.8 Python/3.9.12 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off
```

to:

```
aws-cli/2.7.3 Python/3.9.13 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off
```

via `brew upgrade awscli`